# Running EXE application in GINA beofe login screen (Command line)

Tags: windows, winlogon, gina

I have created a Credential Launcher for Windows 7 and was able to run Windows application after the Tile button click event, it was very easy.

I added a few registry settings and `*pbAutoLogon = FALSE;`.

However now i am now trying to do the same for Windows XP.

Which function I should target or how to achieve the same results ?

Answer (score 1):

I see you tagged your question with "Gina", so I guess you know that Credential Providers do not exist on XP.

Your answer depends on *when* exactly you want to run that program, especially with regards to the secure attention sequence (SAS, or when a user press CTRL-ALT-Delete)

- Before the SAS, use `WlxDisplaySASNotice`
- After the SAS, use `WlxLoggedOutSAS`

Since you don't want to write a whole GINA yourself, you could use a custom Gina that wraps `msgina.dll`. [Here is one I wrote](http://www.paralint.com/projects/aucun/), you can find the original I started from in the Platform SDK.

Using that approch, you get a chance to execute code just before or just after certain events, like running your program after a successful logon, something like :

```
int WINAPI WlxLoggedOutSAS(PVOID pWlxContext, DWORD dwSasType, PLUID pAuthenticationId, PSID pLogonSid, PDWORD pdwOptions, PHANDLE phToken, PWLX_MPR_NOTIFY_INFO pMprNotifyInfo, PVOID * pProfile)
{
    int result;

    result =  pfWlxLoggedOutSAS(pWlxContext, dwSasType, pAuthenticationId, pLogonSid, pdwOptions, phToken, pMprNotifyInfo, pProfile);

    if (result == WLX_SAS_ACTION_LOGON)
    {
        //We have a successful logon, let's run our code
        run_my_custom_code();
    }

    return result;
}
```

There are some caveats, though :

- The code cannot block. `Winlogon` will wait, but your users might not. Spanw a process and let it run.
- Your program will be running with `SYSTEM` privileges, which is a security risk. Sandboxing your process could be hard. If *you* can't break out of it, don't assume nobody can...